# Using Javascript to store form values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a quiz engine where teachers can create a new quiz and add questions to it. The problem I'm facing right now is that when I have written the 4 options for the question and then I change my question type, those answers are lost.
These answers are required to be stored (in some variables or array) so that when I switch back to the previous question type, my answers will appear in the input boxes again.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
<select onchange="question_type(this.value);" name="qtype" id="qtype" class="form-control input-lg" required>
    <option value="">-- Select question type for this quiz --</option>
    <option value="mcq">1) MCQs</option>
    <option value="tf">2) True/False</option>
</select>

<input type="text" size="70" name="option" id="option1" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Option A" required>
 <input class="css-checkbox" type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" value="a" />
   <label for="radio1" class="css-label"></label>


<input type="text" size="70" name="option2" id="option2" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Option B" required>
 <input class="css-checkbox" type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="b" />
   <label for="radio2" class="css-label"></label>
```

Here's the javascript function:

```
function question_type(type)
{
if (type == "tf")
{
   $('.not-tf').hide();
   $('#option1').val('True');
   $('#option2').val('False');
   $('#option3').val('@nottf');
   $('#option4').val('@nottf');
}
else if (type == "mcq")
{
   $('.not-tf').show();
   $('#option1').val('');
   $('#option2').val('');
   $('#option3').val('');
   $('#option4').val('');   
}

else if(type=="mcq" && (!($('#option1').val(' '))||!($('#option2').val(' '))||!($('#option3').val(' '))||!($('#option4').val(' ')))
{
    var a=document.getElementById("option1").name;
    var b=document.getElementById("option2").name;
    var c=document.getElementById("option3").name;
    var d=document.getElementById("option4").name;
    console.log("a is"+" "+a+" "+"b is"+" "+b+"c is"+" "+c+" "+"d is"+" "+d);
}   
 }
```

Now the problem is that my answers are still not being stored and I'm getting a "Empty string passed to getElementByID()" error on the console.
Can anyone tell me if I'm doing it right?

I'm a beginner so I don't completely understand what I'm doing.

Comment: I notice you have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id, change as option1,option2.. Your third if statement will never get executed when else if (type == "mcq") is true . There is also a syntax error in third if statement.

Comment: I forgot to change the ID's when I was posting the question. In my code, the id's of elements are unique of course.

Can you point out the syntax error please @Unknownman ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 inputs with the same ID, and 2 checkbox with the same ID too, this shouldn't be like that.

Besides if you are using jQuery in your function, just keep using jQuery in your last "if".

```
    var a = $("#option1").val();
```

But you need to change the ID of your inputs, not all of them can be the same....

Comment: I forgot to change the ID's when I was posting the question. In my code, the id's of elements are unique of course.